# Is there any difference between my static IP and PC IP

Tags: networking, wireless-router, ip-address

Can anyone advise me as I cannot find any information for this particular question. I need to add my static IP address in htaccess so only I can log in in my website admin panel. My router is assigned with the static IP and my PC is having IP like 192.168.0.101 or something. The question is when I add my static IP in the htaccess file will I be able to access the admin panel of my website through my laptop. Thank you

Comment: Your public IP should be the one you use if your website is hosted externally. Additionally, surely your website control panel should be better protected than using .htaccess?

Comment: The IP that you see from your router is your internal/private IP, not a Public IP. Unless your server is located in the same network that will not work. I would suggest using a Mac address filter instead

Answer (score 0):

First there is nothing PC IP,

**Static IP and Dynamic IP**

**Static IP** is IP were you assign IP manually to Systems

**Dynamic IP** is IP were DHCP(Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol ) server assign the IP.

**Private IP and Public IP**
**Private IP:** Is your local IP of your PC

**Public IP:** The IP provided by ISP or IP which you need to connect to Outside world

**To check your IP address.**

**Go to Run -- CMD -- ipconfig.** 
You can see your local system IP.
If your website is same PC. You can use your local ip in htaccess file.

Other Before that to Access with http://localhost in your browser So your website admin panel may appear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I am using hosting provider and not my PC as a server. Thats why I would like to add my IP address so I can access the admin panel only from my PC. The thing is that when I run ipconfig I see one IP like 192.168.x.x which as I am understanding is assigned from the router. But when I open a website and check my IP address it is showing different IP than the one in the ipconfig. When I check additional information in the website whatismyipaddress it is saying that the IP is static. So can I use it so I can restrict access from different IPs

Comment: When you run whatsmyip. It shows you the public IP. Where I mentioned in the explanation.

Comment: Where is your hosting provider. It's in local network or outside the network for example cloud or other location

Comment: The hosting provider is outside my network

Comment: Then you may have to allow the public IP in htaccess file. Do you have permission to edit htaccess file?  You may also require NAT(Network Address Translation) to be done to your local network but I am not sure. You can try adding your public IP in htaccess file and check once.